# how does one pull information from a cURL request in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, curl

This is the header:
GFC-X-PORTER-PIPE: wZ5u8QgsCsTKR2Wz

Content-Type: application/json

So when you do a get using curl(like below):
curl -XGET -H "GFC-X-PORTER-PIPE: wZ5u8QgsCsTKR2Wz" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://mywebsite.com/employeestatus?key=John.Doe|John%20Doe"

RESULT:
{"name":"John Doe","request_header":{"Source-IP":"50.200.140.2"},"status":"out","update_date":"2017-12-13 08:54:04","username":"John.Doe","key":"John.Doe|John Doe"}

If you look at the result, you will see the status “OUT” (in red font) and that will change as there is a script that runs to update that status. That status needs to be underneath the employee info (except the executives) on this link: https://www.mywebsite.com/contact-us/addison/, https://www.mywebsite.com/contact-us/chicago/, and https://www.mywebsite.com/contact-us/hammond/ and you match their key(in yellow highlight) to the user in the contact-us page of the website.

It should show as “I am IN” and “I am OUT” underneath each user. The “IN” and “OUT” word will come from the database and the “I am” is hardcoded.

Comment: I can't figure out how to pull the output of this request in wordpress

Comment: can anyone explain the downvotes?

Comment: The downvotes are most likely because the question is unclear. I'd suggest that you [edit] the question to improve it -- after reading [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress' built in [`WP_Http`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/) class to make HTTP requests like so:

```
<?php
$client = new WP_Http();

$request = $client->request( 'https://mywebsite.com/employeestatus', array(
    'headers' => array(
        'GFC-X-PORTER-PIPE: wZ5u8QgsCsTKR2Wz',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ),
    'body'    => array(
        'key' => 'John.Doe|John Doe',
    ),
) );

$result = $request['body']; // This is your request output.
```

Then you can do whatever you want with your `$result`, you'll probably want to `json_decode()` it first.